# ETL Process when and how to add in Foreign Keys T-SQL SSIS

Tags: t-sql, ssis, data-warehouse

I am in the early stages of creating a Data Warehouse based loosely on the Kimball methodology.

I am currently investigating my source data. I understand by the adding of a Primary key (not a natural key) this will then allow me to make the connections between the facts and dimensions.

Sounds like a silly question but how exactly is this done? Are there any good articles that run through this process?

I would imagine we bring in all of the Dimensions first. And when the fact data is brought over a lookup is performed that "pushes" the Foreign key into the Fact table? At what point is this done? Within SSIS whats is the "best practice" method? Is this all done in one package for example?

Is that roughly how it happens?

In this case do we have to be particularly careful in what order we load our data, or we could be loading facts for which there is no corresponding dimension?

Comment: This may help, (similar)
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A196713+loading+fact+table

Comment: Thanks, this has pushed me in exactly the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would imagine we bring in all of the Dimensions first. And when the
>   fact data is brought over a lookup is performed that "pushes" the
>   Foreign key into the Fact table? At what point is this done? Within
>   SSIS whats is the "best practice" method? Is this all done in one
>   package for example?

It would depend on your schema and table design.

---

Assuming it's [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) and the FK is based on the data value itself:

```
DIM1 <- FACT1 -> DIM2
 ^
 |
FACT2 -> DIM3
```

you'll first fill DIM1 and DIM2 before inserting into FACT1 as you would need the FK.

---

Assuming it's [snowflake schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema):

```
DIM1_1
 ^
 |
DIM1 <- FACT1 -> DIM2
```

you'll first fill DIM1_1 then DIM1 and DIM2 before inserting into FACT1.

---

Assuming the FK relation is based on something else (mostly a number) instead of the data value itself (kinda an optimization when dealing with huge amount of data and/or strings as dimension values), you won't need to wait until you insert the data into DIM table. I'm sure it's very confusing :), so I'll try to explain in short. The steps involved would be something like (assume a simple star schema with 2 tables, FACT1 and DIMENSION1):

1. Extract FACT and DIMENSION values from the data set you are processing.
2. Generate a unique number based on the DIMENSION's value (which say is a string), using a reproducible algorithm (e.g. SHA1, given same string, it always gives same number).
3. Insert into FACT1 table, the number and FACT values.
4. Insert into DIMENSION1 table, the number and DIMENSION values.

***Steps 3 & 4 can be done in parallel.*** as long as there is NO constraint in place. A join on a numeric column would be more efficient than one of a string.

And there is no need to store the mapping for #2 because it's reproducible (just ensure you pick the right algo).
Obviously this can be extended for snowflake schema and/or multiple dimensions.

HTH